# Combine MongoDB and Postgresql in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, mongodb, mongomapper, mongoid

Is it possible to combine AR with MongoMapper/MongoID?

If so, are there tutorials/documentations for this?

Comment: Yes it's possible. Can you please be more specific on what you want to achieve?

Comment: There's another question that might provide some insight (and who knows, even answer!): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258681/activerecord-and-mongo-mongo-mapper-bridge

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it is a piece of cake.  There really isn't anything special you need to do, just make models with the different adapters accordingly.  This is an example Mongoid document:

```
class Project
  include Mongoid::Document
end
```

For comparison, here is activerecord:

```
class BillingEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Just make sure not to mix them up.  For example, don't include mongoid on a class that inherits from ActiveRecord::Base.  I recommend Rails 3, as it's probably going to release this week, and the RCs have been really solid so far.

Comment: does this still work? I'm using rails 4. Just install mongoid gem and put that one line `include Mongoid::Document` in for example my model and done?

Comment: Looks like that much is the same. Check out the docs here: http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. Can you please be more specific on what you want to achieve? It's even easier if you use Rails 3 because mongoid and ActiveRecords uses ActiveModel as the interface.

Comment: I want to use MongoDB with MongoID for my content data and Postgresql with ActiveRecord for ACID-crucial customer/billing data. Are there tutorials how to combine them? I'm pretty new on Rails.